# Array.prototype.map(callback, thisArg), second argument ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js to write a little game which I want to be available in two different languages.

In order to show the translated lists of the different gamemodes and their respective descriptions, I am using `Array.prototype.map(callback, thisArg)`, but it looks like Node ignores the `thisArg` argument :

```
sendMessage(translated[channel.id].modeList + modes.filter(a => {
    if (typeof a === "string")
        return true;
    return false;
}).map(translated.modeDesc, translated[channel.id]).join("\n"));
```

`translated` :

```
const translated = {
    "chooseLang" : "Choose a language",
    "invalidOption" : "Invalid option",
    "modeDesc" : mode => {return mode + " : " + "<" + modes[0][mode].join("|") + ">\n = " + this.modeDescs[mode];},
    "(channel id)" : global.en
};
```

`global.en` :

```
const en = {
    "modeList" : "Here is a list of available gamemodes :",
    "modeDescs" : {
        "mode" : "description"
    }
};
```

It looks like Node is trying to use `translated.modeDescs`, which does not exist, instead of `translated[channel.id].modeDescs` (`global.en.modeDescs`) :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined
    at Object.ruleDesc (/home/algorythmis/Documents/Game/main.js:89:111)
    at Array.map (native)
    ...
```

So, is Node really ignoring `thisArg` or am I just in the wrong way? And what can I do to have the behavior I want to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), the *lexical scope* is preserved so `this` is referring to the context in which `translated` object has defined in, not the the actual object that holds the reference to the function.

Try to use a regular function:

```
"modeDesc" : function(mode) {return mode + " : " + "<" + modes[0][mode].join("|") + ">\n = " + this.modeDescs[mode];}
```

Or use `call` to explicitly set the context:

```
var data = translated[channel.id].modeList + modes.filter(a => { ... });
data = Array.prototype.map.call(translated, translated.modeDesc);

sendMessage(data);
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Uh, it works. I did not know that arrow function's special behavior, thank you.